# Python replace not replacing everything

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to replace in my .html file all links with slash at the beginning to ../. For example:

```
<link href="/wp-content/themes/newera/style.css?ver=1" id="stylesheet-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

to

```
<link href="../wp-content/themes/newera/style.css?ver=1" id="stylesheet-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

So I've got this code:

```
with open(path, 'r') as file :
     filedata = str(file.read())
     filedata = filedata.replace('href="/', 'href="../')
     filedata = filedata.replace('src="/', 'src="../')
 with open(path, 'w') as file:
     file.write(filedata)
```

And It replaces but not everything. After running function in .html file is this (part of code):

```
<link href="../feed/" rel="alternate" title="avium » Feed" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  <link href="../comments/feed/" rel="alternate" title="avium » Comments Feed" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  <link href="../about/feed/" rel="alternate" title="avium » About Comments Feed" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  <link href="../wp-content/uploads/2014/11/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
  <link href="../wp-content/plugins/fuse-social-floating-sidebar/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="/wp-content/themes/newera/style.css?ver=1" id="stylesheet-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/wp-content/themes/newera/framework/css/jquery.bxslider.css?ver=1" id="oi_bxslider_css-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/wp-content/themes/newera/framework/FlexSlider/flexslider.css?ver=1" id="flex-slider-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/wp-content/themes/newera/framework/css/prettyPhoto.css?ver=1" id="oi_prettyPhoto_css-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.0.1" id="contact-form-7-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css?rev=4.6.0&ver=4.0.18" id="rs-plugin-settings-css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Any ideas why it's not replacing everything?

EDIT:

ok here's full code: https://pastebin.com/n25f0CTh

My full functions is:

```
with open(path, 'r') as file :
     filedata = str(file.read())
     filedata = filedata.replace('http://'+domain, '')
     filedata = filedata.replace('http://www.'+domain, '')
     filedata = filedata.replace('www.'+domain, '')
     filedata = filedata.replace(domain, '')
     filedata = filedata.replace('href="/', 'href="../')
     filedata = filedata.replace('src="/', 'src="../')
     filedata = filedata.replace('href=""', 'href="../index.html"')
 with open(path, 'w') as file:
     file.write(filedata)
```

And variable 'domain' in this exaple is: avium.pl

Comment: Your code worked for me. "file" is a bad variable name, because it is a special key word in python. But other than that, it replaced everything.

Comment: can you share the actual html file you are running this on?  Looks to me like that should work

Comment: Is it possible that your file gets additional data appended to it after your script runs?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've posted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be inconsistencies between single and double quotes, for example in

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://avium.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/favicon.ico">
```

and

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='oi_bxslider_css-css'  href='http://avium.pl/wp-content/themes/newera/framework/css/jquery.bxslider.css?ver=1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Adding

```
filedata = filedata.replace("href='/", "href='../")
filedata = filedata.replace("src='/", "src='../")
```

seems to catch everything